Android Jetpack Compose Navigation 2.8.0 - Return result object - popBackStack(route)
I have a fairly complicated app, where there are screens that open an other screen, and await different values (even objects parsed as JSON Strings) as a result. Then the values are set/changed accordingly.
With this new TypeSafe navigation from version 2.8.0, I am unable to receive any results when calling popBackStack(route, inclusive = false)
My setup is like follows:
The NavHostis like this:
NavHost(
    navController = data.getNav(),
    startDestination = ScreenARoute
) {
    composable<ScreenARoute> {
        ScreenA()
    }
    composable<ScreenBRoute> {
        ScreenB(it.toRoute<SearchRoute>())
    }
    composable<ScreenCRoute> {
        ScreenC()
    }
    ....
}

I open ScreenB on ScreenA like this
nav.navigate(ScreenBRoute(fromScreen= 1, argInt = 10))

I want to return my result on ScreenC to ScreenB like this:
nav.popBackStack(ScreenBRoute(fromScreen = 3, argString = "abc"), inclusive = false )

my ScreenBoute data class looks like this:
@Serializable
data class ScreenBRoute(
    val fromScreen: Int,
    val argString: String = "",
    val argInt: Int = 0
)

depending on the fromScreen variable I am processing the object, and processing the values or arguments in ScreenB
My problem is, that ScreenB is always called with the original ScreenBRoute object having values fromScreen = 1 & argInt = 10 even after returning from ScreenC  after calling popBackStack with some new arguments.
Is there a solution for my problem with this new navigation method?

Use the Navigation Result API (introduced in Navigation 2.4.0). This allows you to pass results back from destinations while ensuring proper back stack handling. If you still want to use popBackStack, try explicitly clearing the arguments before calling it.
